# Is there a way to use my multi-monitor setup for my gaming console?

Tags: multiple-monitors, video, games

I have an ubuntu desktop with a multi-monitor setup. Is there any way to hook up my gaming console (PS4, Xbox) to use my monitors as a single display? I presume it would involve some kind of specialized video card to take input from the gaming console and pass it through, but it is possible at all?

Comment: Do you mean being able to see the output from the PS4/XBox One on the same screen as your Ubuntu desktop? Say for example, in a separate window on Ubuntu? If that is the case you can use a video capture card to record the HDMI from the console and display it on your monitor using a USB cable connected to your computer but this is very tricky in Ubuntu as most capture cards do not support Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I mean displaying the PS4/Xbox display spanning across my 4-monitor setup. That is, can I use the 4 monitors as a single large screen for the PS4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but very hard to accomplish, firstly you are able to setup multiple monitors as a single large monitor using [Xinerama](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo), now for the hard part, you need a video capture card that is compatible with Linux, Blackmagic cards are the most recognised brand which has support for Linux, however you need to compile the [DeckLink](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/decklink) SDK and develop a setup that will work for your use case which would likely consume many hours to get working correctly, also for your use case it is recommended to have a capture card with at least 1080p60 so that gameplay will run smoothly which are also hard to come by and generally expensive.

To put it simply, It is entirely possible to accomplish what you want to do but it is way more hassle than its worth especially on Linux where capture card support is very bleak.